# Keyboard and mouse are glitching windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

I need some help investigating the keyboard and mouse problems. From time to time, the keyboard stops responding and hangs for 5 - 20 seconds. When it is "released" after the hang, it repeats the latest commands very fast. When it is operational - there is no issue at all, everything is completely fine. Only time to time it hangs for 5 to 20 seconds and doesn't respond to the key press.

Similar behaviour is with the mouse manipulator.

It is very annoying, especially when playing a game. I don't have any idea how to investigate this. Another important thing is that when the keyboad hangs - everything else is operational, the PC doesn't hang completely, other tasks are executing, only the keyboard is not responding to any actions. Please advise.

Both mouth and keyboard are wireless.

The PC characteristics are shown below:

```
OS: Windows 11 (licensed)

CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900KS, Socket 1700 LGA (0x1)

Chipset

Northbridge: Intel Alder Lake rev. 02

Southbridge: Intel Z690 rev. 11

Bus Specification: PCI-Express 5.0 (32.0 GT/s)

Graphic Interface: PCI-Express

Memory Type: DDR5

Memory Size: 32 GBytes

Channels: 4 x 32-bit

Memory Frequency: 3200.0 MHz (1:32)

Memory Max Frequency: 3200.0 MHz

CAS# latency (CL): 32.0

RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD): 39

RAS# Precharge (tRP): 39

Cycle Time (tRAS): 80

Bank Cycle Time (tRC): 119

Row Refresh Cycle Time (tRFC): 510

Command Rate (CR): 2T

Uncore Frequency: 3600.0 MHz

Memory Controller Frequency: 1600.0 MHz

Host Bridge: 0x4660

Motherboard:

manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.

product: Z690 AORUS MASTER
```

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Account. Make it a member of Administrators. Log into the new account and see if the keyboard and mouse delays go away.

Comment: Important info: wireless keyboard and mouse, or wired/internal?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the keyboard and mose are both wireless

Comment: Try **wired** keyboard and mouse. Could be RFI causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the glitch appeared to be quite simple. The batteries were discharged. Sometimes we can't see or understand obvious things. The batteries were put inside from the factory and stayed in the keyboard for couple of years.